Error: Must use import to load ES Module:
I've existing ExpressJS project in which I'm trying to add TS.
Using node version v20.12.1.
My tsconfig.json has:
"compilerOptions": {
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
  "esModuleInterop": true, 
  "strict": true,  
  "target": "ES6",  
  "module": "ESNext",
  "skipLibCheck": true
}

My package.json has:
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev app.ts"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  }
}


Error List:
[INFO] 03:37:15 Reinitializing TS compilation
[INFO] 03:37:15 Restarting: D:\test\tsconfig.json has been modified
Compilation error in D:\test\app.ts
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\test\app.ts
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test\app.ts:1:7)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
    at Module._compile (D:test\node_modules\source-map-support\source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\User\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-836053039101899.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-836053039101899.js:114:20)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (C:\AppData\Local\Temp\ts-node-dev-hook-836053039101899.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (D:\ts-node-dev\lib\hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
[ERROR] 03:37:15 Error: Must use import to load ES Module: D:\test\app.ts

Also, if there is other packages which I should consider downloading then please let me know.
So far, I've tried changing the versions of node and target, module of tsconfig.
I cannot recall the syntax, there was one which creates copy of ts files to es6. I'm not looking to try that.
I've already messed-up the code so I've just a file with console.log(), which I'm trying to run.
THANKS IN ADVANCE!

Please edit the question to include a [mre].

https://nx.dev/getting-started/intro
